# How does Streambuilder work when it receives a stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

Since I want to work with multiple streams in parallel, I am interested in how Streambuilder works exactly. Did I understand correctly that when Streambuilder receives a stream, it updates the build method?

Currently, when Streambuilder receives a stream, it updates the state of the entire widget each time. I thought it only updates the child Widget (in this case Text) in streambuilder and not the complete widget.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<Map>(
              stream: NumberCreator().stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data['test']);
              }),
          StreamBuilder<Map>(
              stream: OtherCounter().stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data['test2']);
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to work with multiple streambuilders in a stack in a stateful widget. Is it better to outsource the streambuilders to their own stateless widgets or what would be a recommended architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of StreamBuilders as a pipe or wire or connector. At one "end there is a data" and the other "end is the event-triggered". The "event-trigger" here means the user asked for a data. Stream builder is async system so as long as it receives user input and it can retrieve the data, it will run automatically. So to me, it does not matter how you put it as long as you achieve what you want is better? The best or recommended way is implement after you have finished your way of code so you won't have a headache

Comment: Thank you. The Streambuilder rebuilds only its child, right? so Streambuilder 1 cannot rebuild the Text of Streambuilder 2, ist that right?

Comment: Yes, it only apply to what which widget that the stream builder is responsible to handle

Comment: but in my case it rebuilds also the other widgets in this stack as well. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You put a stack inside of the same Stream or Stream inside another Stream?

Comment: I have only the stack you can see above. in this stack I have some widgets and streambuilders. If one streambuilder receives updates it rebuilds all widgets in the stack. but this makes no sense for me.

Comment: Because we are using the "single-subscription stream". Means one stream that control it all. If you want many stream, than it is call "Messages Stream". The "single-subscription stream" is the most common one. In your case, that is the reason why all the widget is update by 1 stream. Try Google "messages stream" for a proper way to use multiple stream. I only know how to apply "Single-subscription stream"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think it is better to work with provider?

Comment: To be honest, it up to the developer which way they want to handle state management. Provider is recommended by Flutter team itself and is easy to implement. So I cannot say which one is better because it will depend on your situation.